# Symfony2 updating data with a form

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to update the data in my database but unfortunately Symfony keeps creating new data for me. I have the following controller:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request,$id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $product = $em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')->find($id);

    if (!$product) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found for id '.$id
        );
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $product);

    if($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($product);
            $em->flush();
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('green', 'Product Updated!');
        } else {
            //$this->get('logger')->info('This will be written in logs');
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('red', 'Update of Product Failed!');
        }
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_store_product_all'));
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:update.html.twig',array(
        'name' => $product->getName(),
        'updateForm' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I just wondering what I am doing wrong. I new to Symfony

**EDIT**

```
// Acme/StoreBundle/Form/Type/ProductType.php
namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Form\Type;

use Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Category;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('price');
        $builder->add('description');
        $builder->add('category', 'entity',array('class' => 'AcmeStoreBundle:Category',));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'name';
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but what if instead of using `$request` as you do, you use `$this->getRequest()`? You don't need to send `$product->getName()` when you call `$this->render()`. (you object `$form` already knows about your object `$product`)

Comment: You will need to post `ProductType` to work out this problem. It's most likely wiping out the primary key (typically `id`).

Comment: I have updated my question with `ProductType.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your controller is correct (even though you can remove `$em->persist($product)` from your code as the entity is already managed by the entity manager).

I strongly suspect the error is in your twig template and that your form does not point to the right action in your controller:
I have a feeling you have the form submitted to the `newAction` method:

```
<form action="{{ path('product_new') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
{# .... #}
</form>
```

whereas the form should instead point to your `updateAction` method of your controller:

```
<form action="{{ path('product_update') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
{# .... #}
</form>
```

Well, that's a common mistake :)

Comment: Spot on. Classic newbee mistake