# get UserId when the button is clicked

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

i want to update find UserId when the button is clicked.

As an example suppose a user name  "Dell" have a "UserId" "111", so when the button clicked in should select the user and do further action.

That's why i use "$_POST", so when the user clicks the button it return the "UserId".

This is how i am trying to get the the "UserId".

```
$usrInfo = $this->getDoctrine()
                       ->getRepository('myBundle:UserStats')
                       ->findByUserId($_POST);
```

But i think i am doing it wrong, cause it is not working when the user clicks the button.

And based on the UserId, i will update information like---

$usrst =  new UserStats();

```
    $providerStats->setOn(FALSE);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($usrInfo);
    $em->flush();
```

So again the main purpose will be to find the **UserId** when a **button is clicked**. 
Do anyone knows knows how to solve this problem. thanks in advanced.

Comment: are you getting user id before the form is submit ? well you need to first fetch the user before update call.

Comment: @Noman yes i am getting the user and the UserId both, but the only problem i have is the "POST" method

Comment: Hey, you did not use $usrst = new UserStats(); because it is use for add new entry in DB, If you need to update record you have to make object with find($id) function and set value what you need.  And why are you using $providerStats->setOn(FALSE); you did not make object with $providerStats so its not affect anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this (I assume you're using Form Component, it would be better if you post your form):

```
...

public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    ....
    $form = $this->createForm(TYPE, NULL_OR_DATA, OPTIONS);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $username = $form->get('USERNAME_FIELD')->getData();

        $user = (SOMESERVICE_OR_REPOSITORY)->getUserByUsername($username);

        // do something here with your user

        // Flush the changes

        ....
    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Symfony 2, you shouldn't use php $_POST variable but $request

*Example if your field name is "UserId":*

```
$request = $this->getRequest();

if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $userId= $request->request->get('UserId'); 

    $usrname = $this->getDoctrine()
                           ->getRepository('myBundle:UserStats')
                           ->findByUserId($userId);  
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not solve my problem, do you have any other solution !

Comment: Could you post youre complete method, it'll be easier!

Comment: I have update my question, can you kindly have a look :)

Comment: There is a full example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16137492/symfony2-updating-data-with-a-form

Answer (score 0):

I have given the code for update the record in Symfony2:

```
$request = $this->get( 'request' );
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
if ( $request->getMethod() == 'POST' ) {
   $user_id = $request->request->get( 'user_id' );
   $obj = $em->getRepository( 'myBundle:UserStats' )->find( $user_id );
   $em->persist($obj);
   $em->flush();
}
```

Comment: may be i did not explain it well, i need to find the "UserId" when the Button clicks, that's it !

Comment: I have update my question, can you kindly have a look :)